# NightwatchJs - Unable to concatenate a referenced element and text

Tags: javascript, concatenation, nightwatch.js, pageobjects

At the moment, I have a lot of duplicate functions, that only differ by an element name they're concatenated to.

Because they're designed in the Page Object Model pattern, they follow this structure:

**Declaring elements:**

```
module.exports = {

    commands: [fixtureCommands],

    elements: {
        navbarPreferences: '#preferences',
    }
};
```

And then consequently, I can reference the element in the test itself (using the @ symbol preceding the element's name:

```
this.click('@navbarPreferences')
```

Currently - I have this function that concatenates a variable with text. The text is actually in an element that has been declared below it (as shown above in my example)

```
function: function (name) {
var i;

for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var elementName = '#preferences-' + strippedName;
    this.click(elementName);
}
    return this.api;
},
```

However, how can I reference an element (like I can in the above example) and concatenate it with another variable.

```
var elementName = '@navbarPreferences' + strippedName;
```

The above prints the actual text out, not the element itself.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding another declaration structure say "props" with your variable in it. than you can call the variable like this: this.props.your_var
example:

```
props: {
   navbarPreferences: '#preferences',
},
elements: {
       someElement: '#some-element'
   },
```

var elementName = this.props.navbarPreferences + strippedName;